# Query to calculate cost by month using AWS Athena querying

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto

I have a table like below.

```
item_id         bill_start_date         bill_end_date           usage_amount        
635212      2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 3/1/2019 00:00:00.000   13.345      user_project
IBM
```

I am trying to find `usage_amount` by each month and each project. Amazon Athena query engine is based on Presto 0.172. Due to the limitations in Athena, it's not recognizing query like `select sysdate from dual;`.

I tried to convert `bill_start_date` and `bill_end_date` from timestamp to date but failed. even `current_date()` didn't work in my case. I am able to do calculate the total cost by hard coding the values but my end goal is to perform the action on columns.

```
SELECT (FLOOR(SUM(usage_amount)*100)/100) AS total,
     user_project
FROM test_table
WHERE bill_start_date
BETWEEN date '2019-02-01'
    AND date '2019-03-01'
GROUP BY  user_project;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Presto, `current_timestamp` is a SQL standard function which does not use parentheses.

To group by month, I'd use `date_trunc('month', bill_start_date)`.

All of these functions are documented [here](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc)

Comment: Since Athena is based on Presto 0.172, https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions can also be helpful.